# powered led generator works but with other power source with voltage divider at same volts don't

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, generator

As the title say I have a small motor used as generator that generates 0.5ma at 1v that power up my led (slighty). I don't have the data sheets from led(it's a 5mm red led), I suppose the forward voltage is around 1.7v that's why the led is slighty lighting up. The problem is that I want to try to run the led with same voltage from other power supply (0.5ma at 5v). So I made a voltage divider to get same volts as generator but the led didn't turn on.So I tried with 2.2k and 1.2k resistors to get around the led forward voltage and it works just slighty as with generator. So why Can I light up the led with generator at 1v and can't with the voltage divider at same volts?

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: How did you measure the voltage. With a  meter or with a scope? Your motor might deliver some weird waveform where the LED is on at the peak but the RMS is 1V.

Comment: Your English is fine.

Comment: you don't need a divider, just a resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your motor is generating the power, all of that power is going to feed the LED.  However, when you go to use the voltage divider, you are creating a draw on the voltage divider at the point that you are getting ~1.76 volts.  A much better configuration is to think of the LED as a resistor.  It takes voltage and drops amps.
[image]

If you put the LED in the place of the LED resistor, then you have limited the voltage to it and it should light brightly.  Additionally, if you look at the current flow through the 'resistor', you will see that it is ~1.5mA.  That amperage is not likely to be close to the max so you won't shouldn't blow out the led.

Answer (score 0):

a motor used as a gernerator my peoduce an average of 1V but with peaks reaching up to the 1.7V the LED needs for normal operation so your meter reads iV but the more puts out mostly less but sometims more. and that more makes the LED light sometimes.

if you want to experiment with this you could fit a disc with a hole to the motor's shaft and observe the LED though the disc, you will see that the LED brightnes varies with shaft angle

or you could use a high-speed camera if you have access to one.